# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I need to prove using definition, I know how to prove it but I'm having trouble on choosing a $\delta$.

Comment: When proving continuity of $f$ at a point $x$, your $\delta$ will have to depend on $x$.

Comment: If you are allowed to use the topological definition of continuous, then $f^{-1}(a,b) = (\sqrt[3]{a}, \sqrt[3]{b})$ and so inverse images of open sets are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall x,y\in \mathbb R, \exists \delta >0: |x-y|<\delta \implies |x^3-y^3|<\epsilon$

$|x^3-y^3| = |(x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)|$

We need to find an upper bound for $(x^2 + xy + y^2)$

Suppose $|x-y|<1$

$(x^2 + xy + y^2) < 3x^2 +3|x| + 1$

Let $\delta = \min(1, \frac {\epsilon}{3x^2 + 3|x| + 1})$

Comment: @ egreg The function is not uniformly continuous.  This is the definition for standard continuity.  Uniform continuity is: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x,y\in \mathbb R: |x-y|<\delta \implies |x^3-y^3|<\epsilon$

Comment: Yes, it is...(I came for an argument, this is just contradiction.)  I just looked up the defn. to triple check, and what is above has the correct order of quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove the function is continuous at $x_0$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, you need to find $\delta>0$ such that, when $|x-x_0|<\delta$, also $|x^3-x_0^3|<\varepsilon$.

The final inequality can be rewritten
$$
x_0^3-\varepsilon<x^3<x_0^3+\varepsilon
$$
or also
$$
\sqrt[3]{x_0^3-\varepsilon}<x<\sqrt[3]{x_0^3+\varepsilon}
$$
Take
$$
\delta=\min
\bigl(
  x_0-\sqrt[3]{x_0^3-\varepsilon},\sqrt[3]{x_0^3+\varepsilon}-x_0
\bigr)
$$